# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Python programming, currently learning Selenium so please excuse what may very well be a beginner level question.

I installed Selenium using Homebrew, then i tried to execute this on my terminal.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
webdriver.Chrome()
```

And then i get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

I found similar error messages but with a different status code so i can't find a way to solve this be it in the documentation or on StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you download the Chrome driver? If so, make sure the version of the driver you downloaded matches the version of your Chrome.

Comment: Yes i downloaded Chromedriver. I just reinstalled it successfully and i just checked and my Chrome is up to date. Does that mean it's not a problem related to different versions of Chrome and the driver ?

Comment: Your Chrome is up to date but does the version of Chrome match the version of the driver?

Comment: When i run `chomedriver --version` it outputs this 
`/Users/Benjamin/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv-exec: line 47: /Users/Benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/chromedriver: Bad CPU type in executable`

Not really sure what it means but could it be the problem ?

Comment: You just wrote "chomedriver". Was that just a typo? If it's a mac, try https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250777998?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're missing ChromeDriver,

First, find which version of Chrome are you using:

- Click on the three dots on the top right corner (in Chrome)
- Help
- About Google Chrome

Second, find and download the right version of ChromeDriver

- https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Third, Unzip the package and move it to the `usr/local/bin` folder. 
(`usr/local/bin` path worked for me on macOS, might be different for different OS)