# Selenium WebDriver Unable to Find ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Recently I've been trying to do some webscraping, however I am utterly unable to run Selenium's webdriver.

I am trying to run this basic boilerplate code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

web = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=D:\\qc1.log"])
url = 'https://www.google.com/'

web.get(url)
```

However this results in the following error:

```
raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self.path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

From doing some research, this error was because ChromeDriver [was not being found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61820322/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-une)

I can confirm that Chrome and Chromedriver are up to date:
[Chrome Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzOtO.png)
[ChromeDriver Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFfYV.png)

I can also confirm that I have ChromeDriver successfully added as a PATH environment variable

I have tried other solutions, such as using a path instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = 'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe'

web = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=D:\\qc1.log"])
url = 'https://www.google.com/'

web.get(url)
```

however the same error persists.

I have also tried adding options to the WebDriver, but to no avail.

When running without service_args added, the webpage will briefly open, before closing itself with [no crash information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncUSj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the other option of importing the Chromedriver through webdriver_manager like this:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you install the libraries, you are using in your project.

```
pip install -u Selenium
pip install pandas
pip install bs4
```

The rest would be automatically installed into your project.
If you are using pycharm